# Installing nvidia drivers

Tags: drivers, nvidia

```
alan@alan-P43G:~$ sudo apt-get install nvidia-340
Reading package lists... Error!
E: Read error - read (5: Input/output error)
E: Problem opening /var/lib/apt/lists/extras.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty_main_binary-i386_Packages
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

I have this problem I think the ppa arent installing.

Anyone knows how to fix it?

Comment: Can you run `sudo apt-get update`?

Comment: yes i ran it but still the same problem

Comment: i think the problem is with the ppa cause when i run sudo apt-get update at the end it gives me an error like some files couldnt be downloaded we use old ones a things like that

Comment: I think you could try this.